# pablar spinner de una base de datos mysql y obtener el campo id (android studio)

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, volley

tengo una tabla llamada categorías con los campos id y nombre
[image: tabla categorias]

en el spinner muestro los nombres de las categorías. quisiera saber como obtener el campo id_categoria al seleccionar una categoria para luego mostrar dicho id en un EditText.
con  onItemSelected solo logro mostrar los nombres de las categorías.
de antemano muchas gracias.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    spinnerCat=root.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCatProd);
    txtEstado=root.findViewById(R.id.txtEstado);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlCatProd, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("categorias");
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String nombreCategorias=jsonObject.optString("nombre_categoria");
                    listaCat.add(nombreCategorias);
                    adapterSpinnerCat=new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listaCat);
                    adapterSpinnerCat.setDropDownViewResource(androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerCat.setAdapter(adapterSpinnerCat);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

    spinnerCat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            txtEstado.setText("Seleccionado: "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la misma forma como obtienes el valor de la categoria,

```
  String nombreCategorias=jsonObject.optString("nombre_categoria");
```

de esta forma puedes obtener el valor del id de la categoría, usando la llave "id_categoria":

```
String idCategoria = jsonObject.optString("id_categoria");
```